known variance in conjugate normal
$Posterior\ mean=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{2}} + \frac{n}{\sigma^{2}}}\left( \frac{\mu_{0}}{\sigma_{0}^{2}} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\sigma^2} \right)$
Using this updating equation with known variance, what quantity is $\sigma^2$ referring to in practice? I have seen sources saying it is the sample variance and others saying it is the variance of the means observed. Or, if I simulate data to update the prior, do I use the sigma used to simulate the data?

If the variance is known of a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, using a conjugate prior for $\mu$ of $N(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)$, then

$\sigma^2$ is that known variance
$\sigma_0^2$ is the variance of the prior distribution
$\mu_0$ is updated to $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} + \frac{n}{\sigma^2}}\left(\frac{\mu_0}{\sigma_0^2} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sigma^2}\right)$ in the posterior distribution, taking account of the $n$ observations and their values
$\sigma_0^2$ is updated to $\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} + \frac{n}{\sigma^2}\right)^{-1}$ in the posterior distribution, taking account of the number $n$ of new observations though unaffected by their values.

If you wanted to simulate how this works in practice, you would start with some values for $\mu,\sigma^2, \mu_0, \sigma_0^2$, then take $n$ observations drawn from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and see how they change $\mu_0$ and $\sigma_0^2$.  For large enough $n$ you might hope to see the updated $\mu_0$ close to $\mu$ and the updated $\sigma_0^2$ close to $0$.

Thats helpful thanks. So I would use the sigma used to simulate the data, in the updating equation. Not the sample variance? I've been confused by the various different conventions. This example link uses the sample variance as $\sigma$. @Henry

@hovjr That link is slightly dubious: it suggests estimating the population variance from the sample variance.  But if you do not know the population variance then you probably should not be using a normal conjugate prior, and instead use a normal-inverse-gamma prior for the mean and variance of the population.  Its simulations are not for this updating of the prior to the posterior distribution but for the predictive distribution.

"Do not confuse $\sigma_0^2$, which is the variance of the prior, with $\sigma^2$, which is the variance of the observation noise". link equation 12. I am getting stuck on why I am going from the normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ to the sampling distribution of it's mean $N(x_{bar} | \mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. @Henry any clarity would be much appreciated.

In the known variance $\sigma^2$ case, you have a prior and then posterior distribution for the unknown mean $\mu$, and you hope you eventually have sufficient observations to make the variance of this very small when updating $\sigma^2_0$; similarly you want the variance of the sample mean $\bar x$ to be very small as a result of a large number of observations.  But the uncertainty for individual samples in the predictive distribution can never get below that associated with the population distribution variance of $\sigma^2$.  Distinguish between the uncertainty of $\mu$ and that of $X_i$.

Would you have any literature to recommend with a straightforward explanation of the first principles? @Henry

Wikipedia's article on the posterior predictive_distribution has a couple of links.
